# проблема множественного добавления

Tags: javascript

Отслеживаю элементы iteminfo0_item_name и iteminfo1_item_name

```
(function() {
    console.log(1);

    document.getElementById("iteminfo0_item_name").addEventListener(
        "DOMSubtreeModified",
        function() {
            console.log("0");
            inventory_logos0();
        }
    );

    document.getElementById("iteminfo1_item_name").addEventListener(
        "DOMSubtreeModified",
        function() {
            console.log("2");
            inventory_logos1();
        }
    );
})();
```

Потом функциями inventory_logos1 и inventory_logos0 добавляю span (функция inventory_logos1 идентична inventory_logos0)

```
function inventory_logos0(){
    var d0 = document.getElementById('iteminfo0_item_tags');
    d0.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
<span class="item_market_action_button_contents">Слова</span>
`);
    console.log(3);
}
```

Проблема в том что он к моим iteminfo0_item_tags и iteminfo1_item_tags добавляется сперва два span, затем после очередного изменения iteminfo0_item_name или iteminfo1_item_name к уже существующим двум span добавляются еще два span. 
Вопрос, как сделать чтобы страница загрузилась, произошли изменения в iteminfo0_item_name или iteminfo1_item_name, предыдущие два span удалились, а добавились новые два?

Comment: вы вешаете обработчик на изменение DOM элемента, и внутри него опять добавляете элемент в этот же самый узел. получаете условную рекурсию

Comment: как можно избежать это?

Comment: а не знаю. на вскидку 1) добавить переменную-флаг, по значению которой проверять, добавлять ли повторный спан 2) отключать событие при заходе в обработчик, и вешать обратно на выходе из него. Но не думаю что это хорошие способы. Надо гуглить.

Comment: добавь пример разметки к которой это все применяется

Comment: вдобавок _This event has been deprecated in favor of the [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)_

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. вы вызываете вечную рекурсию, предлагаю вам сделать Event listener одноразовым

1. анонимной функции дописать имя и в ней сделать

   ```
   вашЭлемент.removeEventListener(тип, имяВашейФункции)
   ```

Или

2. принять в функции событие(Event)  и сделать

   ```
   вашЭлемент.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee)
   ```

Comment: А можно по подробнее?

Comment: @MegaRoks, после того как ваш слушатель сработает вы его удалите и cделаете добавления спана, т.к. слушателя уже не будет то он собственно второй раз не сработает.
`el.addEventListener('click', function _func() {
alert('test');
//Сработает один раз
el.removeEventListener('click', _func); 
});`